# How to set up container using Docker Compose to use a static IP and be accessible outside of VM host?

Tags: docker, containers, docker-compose

I'd like to specify a static IP address for my container in my `docker-compose.yml`, so that I can access it e.g. using `https://<ip-address>` or `ssh user@<ip-address>` from outside the host VM.

That is, making it possible for other machines on my company network to access the Docker container directly, on a specific static IP address. I do not wish to map specific ports, I wish to be able to access the container directly.

A starting point for the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
master:
  image: centos:7
  container_name: master
  hostname: master
```

Is this possible?

I'm using the Virtualbox driver, as I'm on OS X.

Answer (score 1):

So far it is not possible, it will be in the Docker v 1.10 (that should be released in a couple of weeks from now).

**Edit:**

See the [PR on GH](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/19001).

Comment: Will this really make it possible to define the IP address in the docker-compose.yml though? It seems this will only work when using the `docker` command (with Docker 1.10) and not the `docker-compose` command?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess so.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess so. All the details can be found here: https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/19001#issuecomment-179388268

Answer (score 0):

I believe extra hosts entry is a solution.

```
extra_hosts:
 - "somehost:162.242.195.82"
 - "otherhost:50.31.209.229"
```

See [extra_hosts](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra-hosts).

**Edit:**

As pointed by [M. Auzias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35131632/how-to-define-static-ip-address-for-container-in-docker-compose-yml/35133266?noredirect=1#comment57987922_35133266) in comments, i misunderstood the question. Answer is incorrect.

Comment: I'm not sure that the `extra_host` is supposed to be a container. @fredrik it **will** be possible in the next version of the Docker (v1.10) that should be release in two weeks at most.

Comment: I was under the impression that the `extra_hosts` just adds stuff into the `/etc/hosts` on the container. This doesn't make the container accessible on a specific IP address. @M.Auzias Oh, that is awesome. I might just have to wait a couple of weeks then!

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the IP address of the container with `--ip` parameter when running it, so in that it way the IP would always be the same for the container. After that you could ssh to your host VM, and then "attach" to the container.

Otherwise, I'm not sure... Maybe try and run the container with `--net=host` 
From https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/

> The host network adds a container on the hosts network stack. You’ll
>   find the network configuration inside the container is identical to
>   the host.